# Spring deployment in tomcat 5.5 problem

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-mvc

I have made a web application using spring and spring-mvc 2.5.I also used jdk-5 and tomcat 6 for development.Now I want to deploy it in a live server which is tomcat 5.5 with jdk 6 and I'm facing several NoClassDefDoundErrors such as "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.core.CollectionFactory
".Is there a change to overcome such problems by replacing spring related jars with a newer version such 2.5.6?And in general is there something I can do about this kind of problems?-except changing live tomcat with tomcat 6.This is not an option at the moment - thank you in advance for your time

Answer (score 0):

Do you have all your Spring JARs in your app's

```
WEB-INF/lib
```

directory?  It sounds like you may not do...

Edit: or, you may have these Spring JARs in your development Tomcat's own lib dirs, that's why they're being found in dev but not on your live server.

Comment: In fact I used the war that netbeans created and in the lib folder whrere spring 2.5 jar and spring-web-mvc-2.5 jar

Comment: are those JARs definitely in your exploded webapp directory on the live server?

Answer (score 0):

Can you list all the jars from the WEB-INF/lib directory? You are missing some spring jars.

The latest version of spring is 3.0.5. If possible - upgrade both the JDK (to version 6) and tomcat (to version 6)

Comment: concerning spring I have spring-2.5 jar and spring-webmvc-2.5 jar

Comment: Strange, as the org.springframework.core.CollectionFactory class is indeed in the spring.jar file. Can you please post the entire error message, with all the exceptions/errors?